# What does "seed" mean in "seed the arguments with"?

Tags: meaning

There is an sentence in a document:

> You can seed the arguments with an array of args, but this is only used internally

How to understand the word *seed*? Does the sentence mean:

> You can pass an array of args as the arguments of the function

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site [ell.se]. Also see [seed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seed?q=seed#seed__21), it is a metaphorical use.

Comment: @Matt: This isn't an ELL question; it's a computing terminology question.

Comment: @PeterShor: the use of *seed* metaphorically, regardless the field, seems better placed at ELL. In computing terminology, *seed* is most often used in reference to RNGs, not arguments, so it doesn't seem particularly terminological.

Comment: @Matt _Seed_, as a metaphor, is not **most often** used in anything. It can be used in almost everything though

Comment: @RaduMiron that's not what I meant. I meant that in computing, *seed* most often refers to what you do to RNGs.

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. The citation isn't even "a document" - it's a comment line in [a bit of program code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L248-253), and whatever the author *meant*, he's not using English in any standard way - even for other programmers, who will only know *seed* as meaning *set an initial parameter value for an iterative process* (such as a pseudo-random number generator).

Answer (score 1):

It could mean

> You could *store* the arguments in an array (made out of those arguments) - which (array) could, of course, be used as an argument of a function

But it could also mean

> You could *define* the arguments as arrays made out of other arguments - which (arguments) could also be used as arguments of a function

Maybe you can figure it out from the context.
What program are you using?

Comment: From jquery: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L225

Answer (score 1):

As Matt has stated, the seeding often refers to Pseudo-random number generators.

(The seed informs the RNG how to generate its first pseudo-random number that you ask for. If you used the same seed each program execution, you would get the same list of pseudo-random numbers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-print-hello-world to see how a careful choice of seeds may print out an encrypted message.)

I'm inferring that you may send arguments to your function as seeds. (It's probably not an RNG, which would most likely take a single seed.) If the function were searching for the  roots of a polynomial, then the seeds might function as initial guesses to the roots. If the function were searching for an Internal Rate of Return, the seed would be a guess as to the actual IRR. If you choose seeds that were close to the final value, you would be rewarded with fewer iterations to solve.

In both the RNG and the polynomial guessing, a *seed* provides a *starting point* for the generator or the solver, which is why it works as a metaphor.